# Text.Combine() with separator inside Table.Pivot

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I use this line in Power Query Editor to pivot a table:

```
= Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Rows", List.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows"[Tipo]), "Tipo", "Categoria", Text.Combine)
```

I just need to add a separator to the Text.Combine(). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Text.Combine` with `each Text.Combine(_, ",")` or with whatever separator you want to use instead of a comma.